# Unable to access local css file

Tags: asp.net-core

Local css file called site.css is stored in Content folder in .net core project

Tried the following in layout

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/site.css")" />
```

as well as

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/site.css" />
```

but didn't work.

In startup I have 
     app.UseStaticFiles();

Is there anything I am missing? I am unable to access the css in the browser. Gives error in dev tools.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UseStaticFiles()` only serves content from wwwroot folder. It should works, if you move your css file to `wwwroot/Content/`.

If you want to serve static content from `Content` folder, you should apply config like below:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Content")),
    RequestPath = "/Content"
});
```